What was William Carlos Williams “plagiarising” in Spring and All XIII
In Chapter XIII, it says:

In the imagination, flying above the wreck of ten thousand million souls, I see you departing sadly for the land of plants and insects, already far out to sea. (Thank you, I know well what I am plagiarising) Your great wings flap as you disappear in the distance over the pre-Columbian acres of floating weed.

(Pp 7-8, Emphasis added)
Unlike Dr. Williams, I don’t know well. Is this passage referencing/quoting/plagiarising another poem?

This looks like a nice interesting question - why did you self-delete it? If it's because you already found the answer, please consider posting a self-answer down below (there's an "Answer Your Question" button).

Apologies. As I kept reading, it seemed like "plagiarism" sort of became a theme throughout the rest of the book, and that maybe the answer would become obvious as I kept reading (it hasn't yet)
